# UITableView segue not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue

I followed the SimpleDrillDown app example in the docs for a workout app that shows workout names in the first UITableView and exercises in the second UITableView.

**My app is in Dropbox here: http://db.tt/V0EhVcAG**

I used storyboards, have prototype cells, but when I load in simulator the first UITableView won't let me click and go to the detail UITableView. The disclosure indicator chevrons don't load. The app builds successfully and there are no formal errors.

My tableviews are in a navigation controller, my segue and prototype cells are all named accordingly in storyboard.

#### SpitfireViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dataController countOfList];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WorkoutCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Workout *workoutAtIndex = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = workoutAtIndex.title;

    return cell;
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showExercises"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        detailViewController.workout = [dataController objectInListAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
    }
}
```

#### DetailViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [workout.exercises count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ExerciseCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [workout.exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

#### AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class DataController;
@class SpitfireViewController;

@interface SpitfireAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    SpitfireViewController *spitfireViewController;
    DataController *dataController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

#### AppDelegate.m

```
#import "SpitfireAppDelegate.h"
#import "SpitfireViewController.h"
#import "DataController.h"

@implementation SpitfireAppDelegate
@synthesize window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    spitfireViewController = [[SpitfireViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:spitfireViewController];

    DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
    spitfireViewController.dataController = controller;

    [window addSubview:[navController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

[image: My Storyboard]
[image: SpitfireViewController (Root)]
[image: DetailViewController]

Comment: Please upload your project somewhere and link to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Storyboards, you'll typically set the storyboard file name in the Project settings under the info tab.  Once you've selected your storyboard there, you can basically delete everything except the `return YES` part of the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method.  It's all taken care of for you in the storyboard.

**EDIT:**

Here's where you set the storyboard:

[image: set main storyboard]

Also make sure that your view controller is set as the initial view controller:

[image: set initial view controller]

Comment: Hey Ben - when I do this, I can't see my tableview. The nav bar loads, but the tableview is black.

Comment: I added some screenshots for clarity.  Is this what you have?

Comment: I downloaded your project.  The problem is your tableview is nil when loaded from the storyboard.  If you delete & re-drag a tableview controller onto the storyboard, and ctrl-drag from the nav controller to the new table view controller, set it as root view controller and run it you'll see the table view.  Then you can set the class, configure prototype cells etc.  I think the problem was you started with a UIViewController and dragged a table view onto it.

Comment: Gotcha! Yes I recall dragging a tableview onto a UIViewController. I re-did my storyboard like you said and removed the code in the AppDelegate. My tableview loads and is no longer black, but the cells don't have content, currently trying to figure that out. :P

Comment: My answer also mentioned cleaning up the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method ;)

Answer (score 5):

**If you have tableview cell segue selection issue.**

[image: A Tableview with selection enabled]

- You need to check first that your tableview allows selection
- You do not need to implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` when using "Static cells"
- You need to add a segue for the accessory action + a segue for the selection.

[image: One segue for the table view selection another for the accessory action]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem:

```
    spitfireViewController = [[SpitfireViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:spitfireViewController];

    DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
    spitfireViewController.dataController = controller;
```

The spitfireViewController you create here is not the one in your storyboard, it's a new one. You should delete all this code, as you already have a spitfireViewController embedded in a navigation controller that you made in the storyboard. You should set the data controller for spitfireViewController in it's viewDidLoad method:

```
    DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];
    self.dataController = controller;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Makes sense now. This worked when coupled with @Ben's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Where is your "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" method?

I would recommend putting that in and then triggering [self performSegueWithIdentifier:] to trigger the segue using the data in the table cell as the sender.

Comment: That's not right.  If you're using storyboards, you don't use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` at all.

Comment: @BenScheirman So I'm having a similar issue.  How do you handle tapping a cell to present a detailed Table View?

Comment: typically you'll define a segue from one of the cells to another view controller, and the transition is handled for you.  If you need to provide state to the new view controller you'll do that in prepareForSegue